# SpaProxy or SpaServices.Extensions - which to use for building ASP NET Core app with Angular SPA

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

In a past I created Angular SPA with ASP NET Core using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`. Now it seems to be obsolote, and we rather shall use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`. But when we create project from template, it uses something called SpaProxy.

I'm ultra confused what shall I use: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` or `SpaProxy`. I can't find any documentation about what differentiate them.

I want to have my backend and frontend (Angular SPA) at the same port, e.g 443. I think (but I'm not sure) that I wouldn't be able to use `SpaProxy` in this scenario, because it uses two distinct ports for backend and frontend, and redirects predefined endpoint calls at frontend port to backend port.

The scenario seems to possible to handle by using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions`, because in production I just use static files from `ClientApp/dist/clientapp` or something like this.

But I'm still confused and don't know which to choose, what differentiate them, and especially how the SpaProxy works.

*I use NET7*

Comment: Both systems host both back and frontend on the same port. But with the old system (SpaServices.Extensions) the backend hosts the frontend, whereas with the new template the frontend proxies specified webrequests to the backend. If you're using server side rendering, then you have to use the old system (SpaServices.Extensions)

Comment: Server side rendering? If it's SPA, the whole app is loaded, yes? So server must return whole accessible static content. How can it be done in different way (probably client-side rendering, if server-side rendering exists)?

Comment: SSR is purely for search engines and noscript browsers. The backend renders the page in NodeJS and returns the complete html. If it doesn't ring a bell, you can just ignore that stuff

Comment: 1. I cant find any documentation about SpaProxy. I can use default template, but I see that even for production it runs `ng serve` instead of using built project from `dist`. 2. I think I don't understand CSR (and thats cause of 1th confusion). How can I not return complete HTML?